# error - function is not the function in child class

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, asynchronous, promise

I have a parent class Weather, which shows the weather for 4 days. I have a child class, which gets an array of cities. And he should show the the weather for 4 days for a random city in this array. But I have an error - this.makeRandom(...).then is not a function. What is wrong?

```
class GetRandomCity extends Weather {
    constructor(city) {
        super();
        this.city = city;
    }

    makeRandom() {
       //code
    };

    init() {
        this.makeRandom().then(city => {
            this.getCoordinates(city)
        }).then(coords => {
            return this.getWeatherForecast(coords);
        }).then((forecast) => {
            const { currently, daily } = forecast;
            this.renderForecastInfo(currently, daily);
        });
    }
}

const w1 = new GetRandomCity(['Paris', 'Minsk', 'Madrid', 'Chikago']);
```

Comment: makeRandom is not an async function, you do not need then, then is used for promises.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu how can i pass the city value to function getCoordinates?

Comment: this.getCoordinates(this.makeRandom())

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `makeRandom` does not return a promise. You need to put a return statement before `getCoordinates` if you choose to make it an `async` function. Else, you could change your code in your `init` function to this and it should work:

```
const city = this.makeRandom();

this.getCoordinates(city).then(coords => {

  return this.getWeatherForecast(coords);

}).then(forecast => {

  const { currently, daily } = forecast;
  this.renderForecastInfo(currently, daily);

});
```